# how to get an array of predictions from tensor flow classification model

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, prediction

I have the following classification model. 
I would like to get a numpy array similar to y_t which is the test labels one hot encoded. However I keep getting variable error.

```
# Construct placeholders
with graph.as_default():
    inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, seq_len, n_channels], name = 'inputs')
    labels_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes], name = 'labels')
    keep_prob_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'keep')
    learning_rate_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'learning_rate')

with graph.as_default():
    # (batch, 100, 3) --> (batch, 50, 6)
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=inputs_, filters=6, kernel_size=2, strides=1, 
                             padding='same', activation = tf.nn.relu)
    max_pool_1 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same')

with graph.as_default():
    # Flatten and add dropout
    flat = tf.reshape(max_pool_1, (-1, 6*6))
    flat = tf.nn.dropout(flat, keep_prob=keep_prob_)

    # Predictions
    logits = tf.layers.dense(flat, n_classes)

    # Cost function and optimizer
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels_))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate_).minimize(cost)

    # Accuracy
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name='accuracy')
```

Then I use the test set

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    # Restore
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('bschkpnt-cnn'))

    for x_t, y_t in get_batches(X_test, y_test, batch_size):
        feed = {inputs_: x_t,
                labels_: y_t,
                keep_prob_: 1}

        batch_acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed)
        test_acc.append(batch_acc)
    print("Test accuracy: {:.6f}".format(np.mean(test_acc)))
```

y_t is a nX3 bumpy array.
I want to get a y_pred in similar format

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> soft = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

this will be your probability distribution such that `sum(soft)` = 1. Every value in this array will indicate how sure the model is about the class.

> pred = sess.run(soft, feed_dict=feed)
>
> print(pred)

So basically all I do is place an additional `softmax`, since you have it inbuilt in the loss you calculate, you've to place it again to predict. Then I ask for the output prediction, and just feed the `feed_dict` again.

Hope this helped!